# How to create a kubernetes cluster with service account of type 'compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Service account "abcdefc-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" does not exist.

I am trying to create a kubernetes cluster but GCP gives me the error above.
I checked for the account name in service account but could not find it, rather I have
'ayushaccount@abcdef.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.

I tried to create another service account with this email "abcdefc-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" but it does not allow me to create.

I am new to GCP and I do not know how to solve this problem. All I am looking for to create a kubernetes cluster in GCP.

Comment: Is the name of your project "abcdefc"?  It appears that the default service account is missing from your project.

Comment: To recover the default compute engine service account follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the default service account for your GCP project.
You have two options:

1. (re)create the default service account
2. when creating your GKE cluster, under NODE POOLS, go to default-pool->Security and for Service account, select one the one which exists.

If you want to (re)create the default service account, you can disable/enable the Google Compute Engine API via the console or run `gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com` from Cloud Shell or from the command line on your workstation.

Comment: I am trying to perform second step which is to disable and then enable. but every time I do this, I get operation failed.